# Youtube player tracking API for iframe embed

Tags: iframe, youtube, google-analytics, embed, tracking

I need to enable event tracking of Youtube-videos embedded in a site, but since Youtube has switched to iframe-based embedding-code, I'm kinda lost ...

Google/Youtube documentation ( http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html ) only describes how to enable the API when videos are embedded programmatically using the API itself - not when they are copy-pasted onto a page in, say, a CMS.

On top of that, the documentation states that the Youtube Player API for iframe tracking is experimental and should not be used for production sites!

Has anyone found a way to make this work? To listen to events fired by an iframe-embedded Youtube video?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you may be intersted in this lib. http://code.google.com/p/ga-youtube-tracker/ butI think it only work with the embedded version.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference, on June 6 2012, Google removed the _Experimental_ status.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this can be used to get events and call functions on a YouTube video embedded via an iframe.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Answer (score 2):

There are a few resources available on the web for this:

1. For the DIY'er on google analytics:
   http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/10/22/automatically-track-youtube-videos-events-google-analytics/
2. For someone who's looking for a product catered youtube analytics (currently free):
   http://www.vidanalytic.com/